# How to display results from JSON in new page?

Tags: reactjs

I have a simple app that retrieves data from a local json file, but what I would like to accomplish is to be able to click on any of the movies from the list and display its description in another page. I tried using react-router but was unable to figure it out.

Here is the code:

App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import MovieList from "./data/data.json";

export default class Movie extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Movies:</h1>
        {MovieList.map((movie, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="movie" key={i}>
              <li>{movie.title}</li>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

data.json

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "title": "Movie 1",
    "description": "This is the description for Movie 1"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "title": "Movie 2",
    "description": "This is the description for Movie 2"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "title": "Movie 3",
    "description": "This is the description for Movie 3"
  }
]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it with react router, it's actually pretty straightforward. You would need to set up your router to route to the right page with the movie ID in the URL. So the general idea is this:

```
https://example.net/ -> shows all moves
https://example.net/:id -> shows info for the specific movie ID
```

You will have 2 main components: `Movies` that renders a list of all movies and `Movie` that renders the description for a specific movie by ID.

Here is the code to get it done along with a sandbox link: https://codesandbox.io/s/brave-dirac-8sdmj?file=/src/App.js

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route } from "react-router-dom";

const MovieList = [
  {
    id: 1,
    title: "Movie 1",
    description: "This is the description for Movie 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    title: "Movie 2",
    description: "This is the description for Movie 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    title: "Movie 3",
    description: "This is the description for Movie 3"
  }
];

class Movies extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Movies:</h1>
        {MovieList.map((movie, i) => {
          return (
            <div className="movie" key={i}>
              <li>
                <a href={"/" + movie.id}>{movie.title}</a>
              </li>
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const Movie = (props) => {
  const {id} = props.match.params;
  const movie = MovieList.find(item => item.id === parseInt(id))
  return <div>Movie info: {movie.description}</div>;
};

export default class extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Switch>
          <Route exact path="/">
            <Movies />
          </Route>
          <Route
            exact
            path="/:id"
            render={(props) => <Movie {...props} isAuthed={true} />}
          />
        </Switch>
      </Router>
    );
  }
}
```

Keep in mind that this is a general idea of how to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish. There are much more elegant ways to to write this code.